# Position Speed dial menu (Material UI) above nested div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, speed-dial

Sandbox code: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicspeeddial-demo-material-ui-forked-nt0j5y?file=/demo.js)

I have two nested divs , namely , `speeddial-div` and `outer-div`. The `speed-dial` div has a Speed Dial component from Material UI ([find here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-speed-dial/)) which shows floating icons. Presently when I hover over the component it overflows and a scrollbar appears , the conventional behavior. But I want to display this menu upon hover over the red `outer-div`. Presently it looks like this:

[image]

But I want the print and other icons to overflow on the red div without the need of a scrollbar.
I tried absolute and relative positioning to no result. Any ideas on how I can achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by having the second div with className `outer-div` inside `speeddial-div` . This will make the speed dial component to overlap on the second div instead of overflowing the div.

Working link : [Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicspeeddial-demo-material-ui-forked-cq3edp)

Comment: Ahh this works, thanks , but I'm afraid I can't really move the divs . Is there another way around wherein I needn't change the nesting?